# Retrieve file over serial without kermit and lrzsz

Tags: serial-port, file-transfer, serial-console, minicom, uart

I have an embedded Linux on a custom board and I would like to send and receive file over its serial port.

The only way to communicate with this device is over serial and the device offers a console on this serial port.

This board doesn't have `kermit` neither `busybox rx` nor `lrzsz`.

**- Sending file to remote**

I was able to send file to the board following [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229984/serial-file-transfer-without-lrzsz).

```
Host side                              Remote side

cat file | base64 > file_b64
                                       cat > file_b64
minicom's ctrlA-S => send 'file_b64'
                                       cat file_b64 | base64 --decode > file
```

**- Getting file from remote**

Now I would like to retrieve a file from remote system.

Minicom has a tool for receiving files but as I only have the serial port's console using minicom to issue commands on remote side, I can't find how to do it.

I have tried using kermit on host side but it seems that I also needs to have kermit on the remote side.

---

***EDIT:***

I have also tried to reverse the sending method but with no success as i receive nothing from serial port on host side.

```
Host side                              Remote side

                                       cat file | base64 > file_b64
                                       (sleep 10; cat file_b64 > /dev/ttyS0) &
                                       minicom's ctrlA-X => exit minicom
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > file_b64
```

Can't use minicom's receive tool cause it only support `xmodem`, `ymodem`, `zmodem` and `kermit` tranfers and not ascii.

---

**Is there a way to retrieve files from remote without having to type commands into its console?**

Comment: Why don't you use the slip module to build a tcp/ip connection? http://tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-slip.operation.html

Comment: Didn't know this module, however `slattach` is not available on remote side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found out that I was issuing the wrong command on receiver's side.

Receive command shall be : `cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 > file_b64`

### Summary

To receive from remote :

```
          Host side                |             Remote side
                                   |
                                   |    #Encode to base64
                                   |    cat file | base64 > file_b64
                                   |
                                   |    #Send after timeout
                                   |    (sleep 10; cat file_b64 > /dev/ttyS0) &
                                   |
       #############################################################
       ### Exit minicom but keep configuration (ctrlA-Z, then Q) ###
       #############################################################
                                   |
#Receive file                      |
cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 > file_b64      |
                                   |
#Decode file                       |
cat file_b64 | base64 -di > file   |
```

Answer (score 6):

Summarizing above posts i found something like this:

### Sending.

Start receiving on target:

```
cat | base64 -d > filetotarget.bin
```

Exit minicom with **Ctrl-A + Q** and then run on host machine:

```
cat filetotarget.bin | base64 > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Return to minicom and press **Ctrl-D** to finish receive process.

### Receiving.

Start delayed send on target:

```
sleep 10 ; cat filefromtarget.bin | base64
```

Exit minicom with **Ctrl-A + Q**. Then start receiving on host:

```
cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 | base64 -di > filefromtarget.bin
```